# Why MSVC compiler converts "??-" sequence to "~" in string literals?

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, trigraphs

I have a **hard coded string** in my code (which should be used as a file mask), but compiler always changes the "??-" sequence to "~", for example:

```
const wchar_t textW[] = L"test-??-??-??.txt";
```

The testW will be "test-~~??.txt" (without quotes).

The same happens for non-unicode strings as well:

```
const char textA[] = "test-????-??-??.txt";
```

textA will be "test-??~~??.txt" (without quotes).

My compiler is Microsoft Visual C++ 2008.

I have just tried this with Visual Studio 2013, the string in runtime is correct and intellisense displays the correct value on the tooltip when I'm tracing the app, but... But in the writing mode (when app isn't running) intellisense displays incorrect value with tildas on the tooltip.

Comment: Read about [Digraphs and trigraphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs#C).

Comment: Thanks, completely forgot about trigraphs.

Comment: Most people do, it's very uncommon but still supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a [trigraph](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt0y4awe.aspx), a way to express characters that are not always available on keyboards.

This behavior is controlled by the [/Zc:trigraphs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee462497.aspx) option, which is off by default. It appears it is enabled for your project, I would suggest you disable it.

Answer (score 2):

It's called a [trigraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs#C). They are replaced by the preprocessor.

Comment: Yes, it's a trigraph. But trigraphs are actually replaced in translation phase 1, well before the preprocessor (translation phase 4) sees the file.

Comment: I guess it's an informal use of "preprocessor" to mean the whole process of creating the sequence of tokens forming a Translation Unit .